# How to change the color of the links with javascript?

Tags: javascript, colors, hyperlink

I want to know how can I manipulate all the links on a page with javascript. I can get elements by id's with `document.getElementById(id)`, but how can I get the links? And also how can I get all elements with a certain `classname`? I want to change the color of the link and class elements.

I mean these links:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">This is a link</a>
```

And an example for an element with a class:

```
<span class="link">This is an element with a class</span>
```

**Please no jquery.** I want javascript.

Comment: (jQuery *is* JavaScript -- in any case, the same applies -- set the style/class/or-other-selector of the element and use CSS. In fact, there is no JavaScript required with CSS... there is no trivial way to get all elements with a given class, but you can get all elements with a given "tag name" (hint) -- it's a standard DOM method -- and then iterate those with the appropriate conditional. If you don't want to use jQuery, I would look at the W3C DOM specification for the "standard" DOM functions and then quirksmode to find out all the different ways they *really* work.)

Comment: See the update to my answer. I provided a link that demonstrates what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 19):

Simple and straightforward (in pure JS too!)

```
colorLinks("#00FF00");

function colorLinks(hex)
{
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++)
    {
        if(links[i].href)
        {
            links[i].style.color = hex;  
        }
    }  
}
```

If it's a class name you're looking for and you know the tag, just use this.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for(var j=0;j<elements.length;j++)
{
    if(elements[j].className === "your class here")
    {
        //do something
    }  
}
```

You can also look at [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll). Both have support in most new browsers.

Comment: I've added a quick example for you regarding classes.

Comment: I just want to get the elements with a class name, like: <div class="im_looking_for_all_elements_with_this_class_name">hello</div> Is that possible?

Comment: In that case, you'd substitute "span" for "div" in my snippet and then place the class you're looking for in place of "im_looking_for_all_elements_with_this_class_name".

Comment: `if (links[i].href)...` is unneeded. It's against standards to use `href=` attributes for elements other than `<a>`.

Comment: Oh I did it this way: 

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("link");
  for(var j=0;j<elements.length;j++)
  {
      elements[j].style.color = "#" + color;
  }

Comment: You did a mistake in the second example: you do a for loop with j, but you wrote elements[i], that's a mistake, right?

Comment: Blender, I've seen a fair share of anchor tags without href attributes. That's what was meant by that line as well as my comment. Apologies for not elaborating.

Comment: so do i need to check href also or not?

Comment: Only if you use links without `href`'s (which are basically `span`). I wouldn't, just for code readability, but that's up to you.

Comment: @Blender Actually, the other use for `a` elements without `href` is to act like so-called 'bookmarks', but nobody uses them for this any more. Well, almost everybody...

Answer (score 8):

The pure-JavaScript version isn't all that complicated:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements.className.split(/\s+/).indexOf('red') !== -1) {
        elements[i].style.color = 'red';
    }
}
```

And for modern browsers:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('a.red');

[].slice.call(elements).forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.style.color = 'red';
});
```

Comment: Exactly this, changing colors. But can you write the pure javascript version? How can i get a's with js?

Comment: An error on the loop, should be:for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('a').length; i++)

Comment: By the way, that doesn't find all of the links. A link is an element with a "href" attribute.

Comment: I fixed the loop thing, and added a class selector. @Matt, is it valid (X)HTML to add `href` attributes to elements besides `<a>`?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I still recommend using jQuery, but, if you want to learn how to do it without, I would recommend heading over to this site. This shows how to change link colors when you mouse over the link, but you can easily extrapolate for your specific situation: [Javascript Change Link Text Color onmouseover](http://programming.top54u.com/post/Javascript-Change-Link-Text-Color-onmouseover.aspx)

--

Ottomanlast has a good point about checking out [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) to help you out with this task (although it can be done without the use of a library). However, just so you have an example of what he is talking about, here is how you could change link colors using jQuery.

```
$('.linkClass').click(function(){
      $(this).css('color', 'green');
});
```

This example changes the color of a specific link when it is clicked.

```
$('a').css('color', 'green');
```

This example will change all the links to a green color.

```
$('.linkClass').click(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('oldClass');
      $(this).addClass('newClass');
});
```

This does the same thing as the first example, but this removes and adds CSS classes that you already have defined elsewhere. (I would recommend this method over just editing the CSS directly.)

Anyway, the point I'm trying to make is that jQuery makes it extremely easy to select and then make changes to the objects within your HTML document. You may want to take a look into it.

Comment: I know about jQuery, but I'd like to know how the pure js works, it's not so much more complicated than jquery so why not learn pure js instead? Thanks anyway, the guys who will read this question in the future might find this answer helpful.

Comment: @Maxxon - No problem. Sorry it didn't answer your exact question. However, one thing - doing "pure JavaScript" (which, jQuery *is* JavaScript) can be significantly more difficult than just using jQuery. Not from a language standpoint, but from a development time, compatibility, etc standpoint. It's the reason why many developers don't even consider doing JavaScript w/out jQuery (or a similar library). Check out this awesome post by Addy Osman (and others) about jQuery vs. Vanilla JS - http://addyosmani.com/blog/javascriptuncovered/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.getElementsByTagName("a")`. This function returns an array of the `<a>` elements in the page. Loop over this array, and use `.style.color = "#000000"` in each element.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I change all hyperlink colors (normal/hover):

```
function changeTextHyperlinkColours(inputColorNormal, inputColorHover) { 

    var sheets = document.styleSheets;
    var slen = sheets.length; 

    for(var i=0; i<slen; i++) { 

        var rules = document.styleSheets[i].cssRules; 
        var rlen = rules.length; 

        for(var j=0; j<rlen; j++) { 

            if (rules[j].selectorText == 'a') {
                rules[j].style['color'] = inputColorNormal;
            } 

            if (rules[j].selectorText == 'a:hover') {
                rules[j].style['color'] = inputColorHover;}
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can embed the link text in the span and change the color

```
<a href='www.mydomain.com'><span onclick='this.style.color="red"'>Visit Us</span></a>
```